# Js calendar help does not switch month after december

Tags: javascript, css, calendar

I'm creating a calendar in JavaScript and encountering an issue with switching months. When I'm in December 2023, it doesn't switch to January 2024 but only to December 2024. When moving forward, it only switches months, and the same occurs when moving backward. So, I believe the issue lies in this code:

```
prevMonthBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    currentMonth--;
    if (currentMonth < 0) {
        currentMonth = 11;
        currentYear--;
    }
    createCalendar(currentYear, currentMonth);
});

nextMonthBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    currentMonth++;
    if (currentMonth > 11) {
        currentMonth = 0;
        if (currentMonth === 0) {
            currentYear++;
        }
    }
    createCalendar(currentYear, currentMonth);
});
```

Here is my code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const calendar = document.getElementById("calendar");
    let currentYear, currentMonth;
    const monthNames = [
        "Styczeń", "Luty", "Marzec", "Kwiecień", "Maj", "Czerwiec",
        "Lipiec", "Sierpień", "Wrzesień", "Październik", "Listopad", "Grudzień"
    ];
    const dayNames = ["Pn", "Wt", "Śr", "Czw", "Pt", "Sob", "Nie"];
    function createCalendar(year, month) {
        const today = new Date();
        currentYear = year || today.getFullYear();
        currentMonth = month || today.getMonth();
        const currentDay = today.getDate();
        const daysInMonth = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth + 1, 0).getDate();
        const firstDay = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 1).getDay() || 7;
        calendar.innerHTML = "";
        const monthName = monthNames[currentMonth];
        calendar.innerHTML += `<div class="d-flex title-month">  
            <button id="prevMonth" class="prevMonth"><</button>
            <h2 class="nameOfMonth">${monthName} ${currentYear}</h2>
            <button id="nextMonth" class="nextMonth">></button></div>
        `;
        const table = document.createElement("table");
        let day = 1;
        const headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
        dayNames.forEach(function (dayName) {
            const th = document.createElement("th");
            th.textContent = dayName;
            headerRow.appendChild(th);
        });
        table.appendChild(headerRow);
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            const row = document.createElement("tr");
            for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (i === 0 && j < firstDay - 1) {
                    const cell = document.createElement("td");
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                } else if (day <= daysInMonth) {
                    const cell = document.createElement("td");
                    cell.textContent = day;
                    if (day === currentDay && currentMonth === today.getMonth() && currentYear === today.getFullYear()) {
                        cell.classList.add("today");
                    } else if (new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, day) < today) {
                        cell.classList.add("past");
                    }
                    if (j === 5 || j === 6) {
                        cell.classList.add("weekend");
                    }
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                    day++;
                    if (!(new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, day - 1) <= today)) {
                        cell.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                            if (!event.target.classList.contains("past")) {
                                const selectedDay = event.target.textContent;
                                openPopup(selectedDay, currentMonth + 1, currentYear);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            table.appendChild(row);
        }
        calendar.appendChild(table);
        const prevMonthBtn = document.getElementById("prevMonth");
        const nextMonthBtn = document.getElementById("nextMonth");

        prevMonthBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            currentMonth--;
            if (currentMonth < 0) {
                currentMonth = 11;
                currentYear--;
            }
            createCalendar(currentYear, currentMonth);
        });
        nextMonthBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            currentMonth++;
            if (currentMonth > 11) {
                currentMonth = 0;
                if (currentMonth === 0) {
                    currentYear++;
                }
            }
            createCalendar(currentYear, currentMonth);
        });
        
        function openPopup(day, month, year) {
            const popup = document.createElement("div");
            popup.classList.add("popup");
            popup.innerHTML = `
            <form id="bookingForm" method="post" action="/saveBooking">
                <input type="hidden" name="selected_date" id="selected_date" value="${year}-${month}-${day}">
                <span class="close-button" onclick="closePopup()">X</span>
                <h3>${day}.${month}.${year}</h3>
                <select name="category">
                    <option value="category1">Категорія 1</option>
                    <option value="category2">Категорія 2</option>
                    <option value="category3">Категорія 3</option>
                </select>
                <select name="time">
                    <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
                    <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                    <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                    <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                    <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                    <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                    <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                    <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                    <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Записатися</button>
            </form>
            `;
            document.body.appendChild(popup);
            const closeBtn = popup.querySelector(".close-button");
            closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
                closePopup();
            });
        }

        function closePopup() {
            const popup = document.querySelector(".popup");
            if (popup) {
                popup.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    createCalendar();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the createCalendar function.
When you pass January as "0" in the createCalendar function, it is translated as false. which leads it to get the current month, which is December.

You can do this instead

```
currentYear = year != null ? year : today.getFullYear();
currentMonth = month != null ? month : today.getMonth();
```

Here's a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/adilasif17/pen/LYqXjmm)

Best of Luck!